# Example of closed and discontinuous transformation

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of a closed and discontinuous transformation. This task is from compact spaces section.

I have problem with this, i can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be the identity map from $\mathbb R$ with usual metric to $\mathbb R$ with discrete metric. Then $f$ is not continuous but it is a closed map. Another example where both spaces are compact: define $f:[0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x <\frac 1 2$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. Note that image of any set is closed!.

Comment: Okay, but when f: X -> Y, where X is usual metric on R and Y is discrete metric on R is not continuous? Because closed is clear i think (Every set in discrete metric is closed and open).

Comment: @Victor It is  not continuous. Every set is open in $Y$ and if the identity map is continuous then every set would be open in usual topology which is not true. See also my second example.